# Angular 8/ Reactive Form - Converting result of checkbox event to a string value

Tags: angular

I have my Reactive form with field - Status (which can have values 'A' or 'I'):

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
          result_info: this.formBuilder.array([
            this.getResultcontrols()]),
            status: 'A',
            change_seq: '',
            action: 'C',
        });
```

I want to map field **status** to an input of type "checkbox" - (Toggle values are 'A' or 'I').
When I print this.form.value , i expect to see the value of status reflected as 'A' or 'I' , **NOT true or false**. Can somebody help me with reactive form equivalent of HTML...(not HTML sample based on template driven format)

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to map it yourself? `const value = this.form.get('status').value ? 'A' : 'I';`?

Comment: @ Silvermind .....Very true..!!..Too bad for me not to think of simplest aspects..Thanks so much..!

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the value like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="test($event)"  value="helloworld">
```

```
test(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value)
    return event.target.value
}
```

and then you assign the value of the property status to the result of the function test()

Answer (score 0):

a FormControl exist you has a input or not. I wrote yet in another answer (but I can not find it). Use a input with [ngModel] and (ngModelChange) to control the value of FormControl

```
    <input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="form.get('result_info2').value=='A'"
        (ngModelChange)="form.get('result_info2').setValue($event?'A':'B')"
       [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}">
```

If you use mat-checkbox use checked and change

```
<mat-checkbox [checked]="form.get('result_info').value=='A'"
            (change)="form.get('result_info').setValue($event.checked?'A':'B')">
</mat-checkbox>
```

In a FormArray it's the same imagine you has a form with a formArray, you defined in your .ts a function taht return the formArray

```
  get myformArray()
  {
    return this.form.get('formArray') as FormArray
  }
```

And your form like

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div formArrayName="formArray">
        <div *ngFor="let group of myformArray.controls;let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
            <input type="checkbox"  [ngModel]="group.get('status').value=='A'"
            (ngModelChange)="group.get('status').setValue($event?'A':'I')"
           [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}">status
            <input formControlName="action">
             </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

See that you use an input "ngModel" to control the "check" and a input with formControlName to control the name

You can be an example of all this in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-checkbox-bk242r?file=app/checkbox-overview-example.html)