# Change the value of checkbox to string

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I already saw many questions but I still can't change the value of a checkbox to a string. I need to change the value according to true - false -> 'A' - 'B'. I am using reactive forms in angular.
I got this:

```
...
..*ngFor="let item of myForm.get('people')['controls'];
...
<mat-checkbox formControlName="check"
              [checked]="item.get('check').value === 'A' ? true : false"
              (change)="item.get('check').setValue($event.checked ? 'A' : 'B')">
</mat-checkbox>
```

It has to be in check true if the value that comes is 'A' and in false if it is 'B', I really don't see whydon't set that value on change. I need to send as a string the value of the checkbox

Comment: REMOVE `formControlName`. You has a "mat-checkbox" that change the formControl. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59910767/angular-8-reactive-form-converting-result-of-checkbox-event-to-a-string-value/59919229#59919229

Comment: @Eliseo I saw your comment in that question and I couldn't make it work, however today I could make it work by removing the formControlName. 
Now, if I remove the formControl I lose the reference to that control, and with a button I am enabling the edition of this form (it is in tables).
`(this.myForm.controls.people as FormArray).at(index).enable();` (where index is the row of the table). And this is activating the other controls i have. n my component I have in "disabled:true" but does not affect this control.
[Pls check this img for reference](https://ibb.co/X7qrRpS). Checkbox is enabled

Comment: you always can write `[disabled]="myForm.get('people."+index).enable"`. Remember all the properties of the mat-checkbox referred to the "formControl". The only "but" is to make touched, for this you can use `(change)`event

Answer (score 0):

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  {{form.value | json}} // just for to see the output
  <ng-container formArrayName="people" *ngFor="let item of people.controls; let i = index">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <mat-checkbox formControlName="check" [checked]="item.get('check').value === 'A' ? true : false"
        (change)="setCheck($event.checked, i)">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
  <button mat-button>submit</button>
</form>
```

```
import { FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: "app-test",
  templateUrl: "./test.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./test.component.scss"],
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup
 
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }


  createForm(){
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      people: this.formBuilder.array([
        this.createItem()
      ])
    })
  }

  createItem(){
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      check: ''
    })
  }


  addItem(){
    this.people.push(this.createItem());
  }


  get people(){
    return this.form.get("people") as FormArray;
   }

   setCheck(checked, index){
     this.people.controls[index].get("check").setValue(checked ? 'A' : 'B');
  }

  submit(){
    console.log(this.form.value);  
  }
}
```

and one more thing, try to use presentation logic in the component class.
**style guide**:  Style 05-17.
link: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#put-presentation-logic-in-the-component-class

Comment: I appreciate the guide link, I will take a look at it. I'm new to Angular. I need to get the controlName from a formArray in my case, now i got this: `this.myForm= fB.group({people: this.fB.array([..])});`
It would look something like `this.myForm.get('people.check').setValue(..)` right?

Comment: can you show me the form itself? For the correct way, we need to see how you build your reactive form.

Comment: @Heybat, you need remove the `formControlName`. We are changing the value of a FormControl, but this FormControl can not "to be" in the screen. remember, a FormControl exists by seft, it needn't any input in .html

Answer (score 0):

First, if you create many many checkboxes inside a loop, and you set formControlName to a specific one, every checkbox will be bind to 1 control. (You will check and uncheck all of them with the same click.)

On second, you should use formControlName, in formGroup:

```
<div [formGroup]="myForm">
...
..*ngFor="let item of myForm.get('people')['controls'];"
...
<mat-checkbox formControlName="check"
              [checked]="item.get('check').value === 'A' ? true : false"
              (change)="item.get('check').setValue($event.checked ? 'A' : 'B')">
</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

On Third, I suggest to use brackets in ngFor and '' to look for control name as string.

```
[formControlName]="'check'"
```

And finally, I suggest to use mat-checkbox's (change) event, and call a custom function, and do whatever you want on ts side:

```
<mat-checkbox [formControlName]="'check'" (change)="someFunction(item, $event)"></mat-checkbox>
```

And in ts:

```
someFunction(item, event){
  ...//Do your black magic here
}
```

By the way: If you use reactive form, and bind a controls to a checkbox, it's value always will be boolean, cuz it's logic... You should decide to map the value later to 'A' or 'B', but you shouldn't use the same time.
And backwards: The checkbox will always work with true or false, width FormControl.
Think about it: You want a Control to control true or false value, but you force 'A' or 'B' in it... It's illogic.
Please re-think your solution.