# Can we send value as Y if checkbox is checked and value as N if checkbox is unchecked in angular?

Tags: angular, checkbox

I want to pass checkbox value as Y if it is checked and values as N if checkbox is uncheked.
this is my checkbox code in html file

```
  <div class="col-sm-12">  
                      <label style="padding-left: 6px;">Status:</label>
                      <span style="padding-left: 10px;"></span>   
                     <input type="checkbox"                     
                     formControlName="Status" style="margin-left: 10px;" 
                     [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted &amp;&amp; addTermForm.controls.Status.errors }">
                  
                     <div *ngIf="submitted &amp;&amp; addTermForm.controls.Status.errors" class="text-danger">
                     <div *ngIf="addTermForm.controls.Status.errors">
                       Status is required
                     </div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
```

this is my ts file validation

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.termEditForm();
    this.addTermForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      RuleName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z# ]*')]],
     // Dealer_Id: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[0-9]*')]],
      Type:  ['', [Validators.required]],
      Status:  ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
   }
```

Comment: use [ngModel] and (ngModelChange) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59910767/angular-8-reactive-form-converting-result-of-checkbox-event-to-a-string-value/59919229#59919229. Yes, you can use [(ngModel)] inside a formGroup and it's indicate in this situation.

Comment: Yeah. i tried it but i'm getting error (didn't work in my code). Can you please elaborate your explanation ?

Comment: I put an answer. The idea is the same: a FormControl exist because you declare in the .ts, it's independient of the .html. You use "some" in html to change the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// replace your 
<input type="checkbox" formControName="Status"...>
//by
<input type="checkBox" 
       [ngModel]="addTermForm.get('Status').value=='Y'?true:false"
       (ngModelChange)="addTermForm.get('Status').setValue($event?'Y':'N')"
       [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"
       [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': submitted && addTermForm.get('Status').errors}">
```

As you see all the "variables" you use normally in a input checkbox using [(ngModel)] use values of the `addTermForm.get('Status')`

Comment: I tried this. But, value of status is saved as null. Don't know why? do we need to bind ngmodel to validation in ts file ?

Comment: I made a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8nxwxl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts. See that is not neccesary bind ngModel to validation. The error is given by the formControl. BTW the "Validators.required" not make nothing in the Status, "Y" or "N" give no error, you can create a custom error -I made one in the stackblitz-