# why checkbox showing true and false in angular

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-forms

I have created checkbox in angular but when I selected all the checkbox it shows me true and false. But I am trying to get checkbox value not true and false in reactive form.

```html
<input type="checkbox" formControlName="services" id="checkbox4" value="transcription">
<label for="checkbox4"><span>Transcription</span></label>
<input type="checkbox" formControlName="services" id="checkbox3" value="translation">
<label for="checkbox3"><span>translation</span></label>
```

I am getting true in return not the value of checkbox.

How i can get the value?

Comment: can you create a Stackblitz example?

Comment: a checkbox only has two possible values: true and false. You can use some similar to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65232020/can-we-send-value-as-y-if-checkbox-is-checked-and-value-as-n-if-checkbox-is-unch/65233755#65233755)

Comment: You should show complete code, as well as the component.ts

Comment: Actually in laravel i used checkbox with like this services[] and it get all the selected values.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to recreate your checkbox sample and it works perfectly fine.

1. Wrap the input into form.
2. Create formgroup for the both inputs.

**In your component.ts file**

```
form: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      services: new FormControl()
    });
  }

  getValues(event: Event) {
    console.log(event.target.value, event.target.checked);
    this.selectedCheckbox[event.target.value] = event.target.checked;
  }
```

**In your component.html**

```
<form (change)="getValues($event)" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    formControlName="services"
    id="checkbox4"
    value="transcription"
  />
  <label for="checkbox4"><span>Transcription</span></label>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    formControlName="services"
    id="checkbox3"
    value="translation"
  />
  <label for="checkbox3"><span>translation</span></label>
  <p>Selected value: {{ selectedCheckbox | json }}</p>
</form>
```

Complete sample:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hekmvm?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: if type is **radio** works, but type="checkbox" has only two values: true and false. You can see if you add in .html `{{form?.value|json}}`

Comment: It still giving true and false. I want selected value not true and false like service=[translation, transcription]

Comment: @majid check the answer and the sample from stackblitz now, I have corrected it.