# Angular reactive forms how to control the checked status of checkbox

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have issue by setting the **checked** status of a checkbox control in reactive Angular form.

I would like to edit the value based on the checked status, but it looks the value controls the status.

For example when my checkbox is Checked I would like this formControl to have value of 'Man' and when not checked value of 'Woman'. Both of those produce true and the checkbox is always checked.

I set the **[checked]** attribute, but noticed that main model take control over the input state.

```
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
        [id]="field.key"
        [formControlName]="field.key" 
        [checked]="formControl.value === 'Man'" (change)="onCheckChange($event)">


  onCheckChange($event: any) {
    let val = $event.target.checked ? 'Man' : 'Woman';
    this.formControl.patchValue(val);
  }
```

Is it possible to achieve such functionality?

Comment: What is `this.formControl`? Is it the checkbox? Checkboxes only take values of `true` and `false` so that wouldn't work. Wouldn't a radio button be the smarter option?

Comment: this.formControl is the formControl itself (this.form.get(this.field.key)). The values are just for example, I need to develop such functionality/ behavior

Comment: I'm unsure what the problem is, can you provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

A checkbox is either true or false. It can't be a string.

If you wish to make it a string, you can either :

- Declare it outside of your form group, and make it update a field of your form group :

```js
form = this.formBuilder.group({
  sex: ''
});

sexControl = new FormControl(true);

ngOnInit() {
  // Be careful of memory leaks here
  this.sexControl.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    const sex = val ? 'Male' : 'Female';
    this.form.patchValue({ sex });
  });
}
```

- Update the value when you submit your form :

```js
  onSubmit() {
    const { sex, ...value } = this.form.value;
    value.sex = sex ? 'Male' : 'Female';
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65232020/can-we-send-value-as-y-if-checkbox-is-checked-and-value-as-n-if-checkbox-is-unch/65233755#65233755

Comment: I wouldn't want my HTML to contain as much logic, but the idea remains the same @Eliseo

Comment: Yes, I feel yours it's a good preference, but I don't like subscribe :)

Comment: True that, if you don't know how to manage your subscriptions, leaks will arise !

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this be a perfect candidate for having radio buttons instead?

```
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio"
        [id]="field.key"
        [formControlName]="field.key" 
        value="Men" />

  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio"
        [id]="field.key"
        [formControlName]="field.key" 
        value="Female" />
```

If that's not the case, you have to write your own custom form control to control this behavior. Mainly combination of `writeValue`/`onChange` method execution would decide the value to be set.

```
const CHECKBOX_VALUE_ACCESSOR: Provider = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyCheckboxControlValueAccessor),
  multi: true,
};

@Directive({
  selector:
      'input[type=checkbox][formControlName],input[type=checkbox][formControl],input[type=checkbox][ngModel]',
  host: {'(change)': 'updateValue($event.target.checked)', '(blur)': 'onTouched()'},
  providers: [CHECKBOX_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class MyCheckboxControlValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {

  onChange = (_: any) => {};

  onTouched = () => {};

  constructor(private _renderer: Renderer2, private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  protected setProperty(key: string, value: any): void {
    this._renderer.setProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, key, value);
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => {}): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  
  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.setProperty('disabled', isDisabled);
  }
  
  updateValue(value: any) {
    const valueToUpdate = (value === true) ? 'Male': 'Female';
    this.onChange(valueToUpdate);
  }
  
  writeValue(value: string) {
    this.updateValue(value);
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    myCheckbox
    #cb
    formControlName="sex"
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

We could pass second configuration option to `patchValue` in order to prevent View being updated when checkbox is unchecked. This can be done by setting `emitModelToViewChange: false`

```
onCheckChange($event: any) {
    const val = $event.target.checked ? 'Man' : 'Woman';
    if (val === 'Man') {
      this.field.patchValue(val);
    } else {
      this.field.patchValue(val, { emitModelToViewChange: false });
    }
  }
```

**[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xdcrni?file=src/main.ts)**

Comment: Good, but how to define the first value? The first state of the checkbox?

Comment: you can do same patchValue inside ngOnInit based on intial value

Comment: Since I did that it assumes the value as true and set property always to checked state

Comment: While patching Even if you pass the emitModelToViewChange: false also it is being checked?

Comment: I update the stack blitz you may need to use setTimeOut or promise in order to fix the sync issues faced by forms

Comment: @Chellappanவ I have tried deep nested form array ex : menu{submenu:[],nestedmenu:[]}. But i got error. I have attached working code URL
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pezmpp?file=src/form.component.ts

Comment: hi @Arunkumar Busy with other works will check

Answer (score 0):

More simple, it's like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65232020/can-we-send-value-as-y-if-checkbox-is-checked-and-value-as-n-if-checkbox-is-unch/65233755#65233755)

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
        [ngModel]="this.form.get(field.key).value=='Man'"
        (ngModelChange)="this.form.get(field.key).setValue($even?'Man':'Woman')"
        [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"
</input>
```

The "key" is **not** use formControlName. We can use [ngModel] to change a FormControl. Remember a FormControl exist always (it's not neccessary a input with formControl)

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to detach the input from the formControl and assign some of the listeners

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [disabled]="formControl.disabled"
[id]="field.key" 
[checked]="field.value === 'True'" 
(change)="onCheckChange($event)">
```

That cause some other small issue, but for my task it works.

In general not recommend such solutions.

I rethink the entire concept and finally decide to pass boolean values and after submit to transform their values. Thanks for the support!