# how to get 0 value from angular material checkbox

Tags: angular

i'm biginner in angular ,i use in my form mat-checkbox :

```
 <mat-card-content [formGroup]="formGroupContent">
    <section>
             <mat-checkbox formControlName="confirmcheck" [checked]="false">admin confirm 
             </mat-checkbox>
    </section>
 </mat-card-content>
```

in ts file :

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.formGroupContent = this.formBuilder.group({
        confirmcheck:new FormControl('')
        });

const chk=this.formGroupContent.value.confirmcheck;
```

When the form is loaded and initialized and i want to save form content in database, the checkbox return value for chk variable is undefined ,but after any checking or unchecking it return true value(0 or 1).
how to get 0 value after form initializing?

Comment: **not** use [checked] and formControlName in the same tag. If you're mannage a FormControl only use FormControlName -or [formControl]-. If you want to have as value in a formControl 1 or 0 instead of true/false, you can check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59910767/angular-8-reactive-form-converting-result-of-checkbox-event-to-a-string-value/59919229#59919229)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize the FormControl with the value you want, programmatically you can do the following:

```
this.formGroupContent.get('confirmcheck').setValue(false)
```

Or better directly in the initialization of the form group:

```
this.formGroupContent = this.formBuilder.group({
      confirmcheck: new FormControl(false)
})
```

If that does not suit you, you can always cast the value to a strict boolean:

```
!!this.formGroupContent.value.confirmcheck
```