# Toggle Angular checkbox with string values instead of boolean true/false

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, checkbox, angular-forms

I have to create three checkboxes in my form and their values need to toggle as "optin" and "optout"  (string) as I check/uncheck the checkbox. Also I need to check all the checkboxes by default for "optin" value. I cannot figure out any solution, any help would be really appreciated :( as I am fairly new to angular

Here is the code I am working on

component.html

```html
<form [formGroup]="optOutForm" (ngSubmit)="submitOptFormValue()">
    <div class="form-group">

   <input type="checkbox" formControlName="optOutFlag1" id="privacy" aria-labelledby="check1">
   <label for="privacy" id="check1"> Checkbox 1</label><br><br>

   <input type="checkbox" formControlName="optOutFlag2" id="security" aria-labelledby="check2">
   <label for="security" id="check2"> Checkbox 2</label><br><br>

   <input type="checkbox" formControlName="optOutFlag3" id="consent" aria-labelledby="check3">
   <label for="consent" id="check3"> Checkbox 3</label><br><br>

   <button> Submit Preference </button>

</div>
</form>
```

component.ts file

```js
optOutForm:FormGroup
this.optOutForm=this.fb.group({
    optOutFlag1:["optin",Validators.required],
    optOutFlag2:["optin",Validators.required],
    optOutFlag3:["optin",Validators.required]
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59910767/angular-8-reactive-form-converting-result-of-checkbox-event-to-a-string-value/59919229#59919229. That's you use [ngModel]="if the value of the formControl is 'optin'" and (ngModelChange)="set the value of the formControl if $event==true 'optin' and if is false 'optout'

Comment: Thank you so much @Eliseo and frank for making it work. I have pasted my solution that is working :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is based on the [solution link by Eliseo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59910767/angular-8-reactive-form-converting-result-of-checkbox-event-to-a-string-value/59919229#59919229).

The checkbox toggles values as "optin" or "optout" when checked/unchecked and is initialized as "optin" by default in .ts file

component.html file

```
<form [formGroup]="optOutForm" (ngSubmit)="submitOptFormValue()">

   <div class="form-group">

   <div class="optClass">
           <input  type="checkbox" 
           [ngModel]="optOutForm.get('optOutFlag1')?.value==='optin'"
           (ngModelChange)="optOutForm.get('optOutFlag1').setValue($event?'optin':'optout')"  
           [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}" id="privacy">

           <label "for="privacy" id="check1">Checkbox 1</label>
  </div>

 <div class="optClass">
           <input  type="checkbox" 
           [ngModel]="optOutForm.get('optOutFlag2')?.value==='optin'"
           (ngModelChange)="optOutForm.get('optOutFlag2').setValue($event?'optin':'optout')"  
           [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}" id="security">

           <label "for="security" id="check1">Checkbox 2</label>
  </div>

 <div class="optClass">
           <input  type="checkbox" 
           [ngModel]="optOutForm.get('optOutFlag3')?.value==='optin'"
           (ngModelChange)="optOutForm.get('optOutFlag3').setValue($event?'optin':'optout')"  
           [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}" id="consent">

           <label "for="consent" id="check1">Checkbox 3</label>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

component.ts file

```
optOutForm:FormGroup

constructor(private fb:FormBuilder){}

ngOnInit(){
 this.optOutForm=this.fb.group({
    optOutFlag1:['optin',Validators.required],
    optOutFlag2:['optin',Validators.required],
    optOutFlag3:['optin',Validators.required]
   });
}
```

Comment: I find this approach makes your template hard to read. But if it works, and that's what you want to do, no problem.

Answer (score 2):

With checkboxes, the Angular form control value is bound to the "checked" state (not the "value" attribute), so it should be either `true` or `false`.

Also, you are mixing reactive forms and template-driven forms. You probably should do one or the other.

##### Template-Driven Form

If you want to use template-driven forms, you can change your template like this:

```
...
<form name="optOutForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #f="ngForm">
   <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="privacyOptIn" id="privacyOptIn" 
         [(ngModel)]="optIn.privacy" required>&nbsp;
      <label for="privacyOptIn">Privacy</label>
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="securityOptIn" id="securityOptIn"
         [(ngModel)]="optIn.security" required>&nbsp;
      <label for="securityOptIn">Security</label>
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="consentOptIn" id="consentOptIn"
         [(ngModel)]="optIn.consent" required>&nbsp;
      <label for="consentOptIn">Consent</label>
   </div>
   <button>Submit Preference</button>
</form>
...
```

And have your component like this. Notice the model `optIn` has properties all set to `true` so the checkboxes are ticked by default.

```
export class MyComponent {
    optIn: {
        privacy: boolean;
        security: boolean;
        consent: boolean;
    } = {
        privacy: true,
        security: true,
        consent: true
    };

    onSubmit() {
        ...
    }
}
```

[See Stackblitz example here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-driven-forms-required-checkbox-bf36yn)

##### Reactive Form

If however, you want to go reactive forms, you can change your template like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
   <div>
       <input type="checkbox" formControlName="privacyOptIn" id="privacyOptIn">&nbsp;
       <label for="privacy">Privacy</label>
   </div>
   <div>
       <input type="checkbox" formControlName="securityOptIn" id="securityOptIn">&nbsp;
       <label for="security">Security</label>
   </div>
   <div>
       <input type="checkbox" formControlName="consentOptIn" id="consentOptIn">&nbsp;
       <label for="consent">Consent</label>
   </div>
   <button>Submit Preference</button>
</form>
```

Then you can set the form in your component like this:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    form: FormGroup;
    submitted = false;

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            privacyOptIn: [true, Validators.required],
            securityOptIn: [true, Validators.required],
            consentOptIn: [true, Validators.required]
        });
    }

    // Convenience getter for easy access to form fields
    get f() { return this.form.controls; }

    onSubmit() {
        ...
    }
}
```

[See Stackblitz example here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-required-checkbox-ykgq6y)

**UPDATE**

If you want your component to return/emit `'optin'` or `'optout'` strings, you can simply introduce a new variable in the component during form submission:

```
export class MyComponent {
    @Output() options = new EventEmitter<{
        privacy: string;
        security: string;
        consent: string;
    }>();
    ...

    onSubmit() {
        const emittedOptions = {
            privacy: this.optIn.privacy ? 'optin' : 'optout',
            security: this.optIn.security ? 'optin' : 'optout',
            consent: this.optIn.consent ? 'optin' : 'optout',
        }
        this.options.emit(emittedOptions);
    }
```

[See it work here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-driven-forms-required-checkbox-mfsmez)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation :] really appreciate it.Also how can we set checkbox values as strings instead of boolean, after submitting the form instead of getting true/false what i really need is "optin" for checked state and "optout" for unchecked state

Comment: @blume0F, see my update to my answer

Comment: instead of changing value in component can we do it in html.  Using console.log(this.optOutForm.value) should display the string values of checkbox

Comment: Is there a way to bind the checkbox to the value property instead of its checked property? Like its null if not, check and when its checked it the value property

Comment: there should be a none template way of doing this

Comment: We can do a (change) on the checkbox and patch the form control with the value property. Here is a stackbliz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ugcary?file=src/app/app.component.ts.